# Too Many connections error in MySQL but not many users are logged

Tags: python, mysql

I have a really weird problem with the error of `Too Many Connections`

The `max_connection` variable is set to `100`.

My DB is accessed only by 1 transactions which updates a table when someone buys item in my online store (with PayPal IPN system). Basically PayPal invoke a script which logs into my db and remove quantity from the product.

Only me and/or the automated remove quantity process are working on this data base.
There are no other users... This makes this error very weird.

I have no idea what should I do next... this error makes no sence. 
Everything I read about this error is that I should increase the `max_connection` but why should I? When I do

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

it gives me less than `10`.

What else could this error means?

I'm working on version 5.0.96 (I know its old) - Is there a known bug about it which was fixed later on?

**EDIT:**

This is my code (Python):

```
try:
    db=MySQLdb.Connect(user=USR,passwd=PSS,db=DB_1, host=HOST1)
    crs = db_remote.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

         actions on data

    crs.execute("COMMIT")
    crs.close()
    db.close()
    return True
except:
    return False
```

Comment: You are probably leaking database connections.  If so, that is a bug in your application.

Comment: @StephenC any connection that is open is also closed. This process is working for few years and never had that problem. Even if I do leak, there has to be a batch of 95+ orders simultaneously for this case to happen... We never had that.

Comment: `SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST` (it might show a lot of sleeping connections) and `SHOW STATUS LIKE '%conn%'` (especially: `max_used_connections` -> this will probably be 100) should allow you to check what is going on.

Comment: @avi - Nevertheless, that is still the most likely explanation.  Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: @Solarflare only 2 processes.

Comment: @StephenC see edit to the post

Comment: Looks like Stephen was right. You don't close your connection in your `except`, so if something went wrong, it will keep open for a while. To test if that was the problem, you could intentionally raise an error in your block (and call that file some times). You couldadd a `finally` to make sure you close your connection in every case. Also you might want to add a `rollback` in your `except`-block (depending on the rest of your code).

Comment: Yup.  That's the problem.  Each time there is an exception, your current code will leak a connection.

Comment: @Solarflare it doesn't make any sense... I get this errors only when connection fails. If connection fail then it didn't open connection in the first place. And again, the limit is 100. even if connection fails it will need 90 + other connections for this overhead. I never have more than 3 orders at the same time. normally I have 1-2 orders per day.

Comment: @StephenC see my last comment

Comment: Even if this is not (ultimately) the cause of your problems, it is a bug and you need to fix it.  Notwithstanding that it doesn't make sense to you.